# When adding a tag in an HTML section, adds blank line above header

Tags: html

Any tag (p>, div>, h3>) inserted as a first tag inside section> #firstentry adds empty line above header. Checked all CSS, no it's HTML. If I remove div> (marked with **** in the code sample) the empty line disappears. Same if I use any other tags, except b>, and same with other pages. I think I'm doing something wrong in the #firstentry section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Anna Putane | Designer</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">    
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="index.html" id="logo">     
    </header>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <section id='firstentry'>
          ****<div class="entry">****         
              <b style="font-size:19px;">How I became</b>
              <p>Like many of us, I've been dreami
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you mean? And the relevant CSS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/piladzisi/9D4x6/3/

Comment: This is my first question, unfortunately can't add any images, need a better reputation. I set up jsfiddle. Same there, uncomment div and white space pop-ups above the header. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float: left;` property in your CSS `header` selector is responsible for the empty space above the header.

`float:left` indicates that the `header` should float the following content on the left side. So the `header` and `section` should be displayed side by side. If that is so, the `margin-top` of your `entry` class goes through the `section` and you have the empty space above the `header`. Just because you have set the `header` to `width: 100%;` the containers are stacked: Here is a stripped down jsfiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/9D4x6/7. For much more details on the CSS box model see: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box.

Comment: Fabian, I removed the float and added clearfix. Works! Would be interesting to understand how it works. thank you!

Comment: @user2578998 I added some more details to the answer. It would be kind, if you accept and upvote my answer - so other users can benefit from knowing that the answer works and having the question marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In your demo, in the css on line 190 you have

```
.entry{
    margin-top: 40px;   
}
```

I commented it out here, and left the `<div class="entry">` in. Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/9D4x6/5/